# cannot install program onto other computers

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, clickonce

i have published a "preview" version of my winforms application, and i have put it out to 2 different computers. When I run the ClickOnce, it says cannot be installed, contact vendor, and the Setup file doesnt even run, it just shows the loading mouse for a tenth of a second and thats it, nothing in task manager, nothing. Can anyone help?

Here is the clickonce log:

> > PLATFORM VERSION INFO   Windows             : 6.0.6002.131072 (Win32NT)     Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.4016    System.Deployment.dll       :
> >     2.0.50727.4016 (NetFxQFE.050727-4000)     mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.4016 (NetFxQFE.050727-4000)     dfdll.dll           : 2.0.50727.4016 (NetFxQFE.050727-4000)     dfshim.dll          : 2.0.50727.4016
> >     (NetFxQFE.050727-4000)
>
> SOURCES   Deployment url          :
>   file:///C:/Users/testMachine/Desktop/Event%20Control.application
>
> ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these
>   errors are listed later in the log.   * Activation of
>   C:\Users\testMachine\Desktop\Event Control.application resulted in
>   exception. Following failure messages were detected:      + Exception
>   reading manifest from
>   file:///C:/Users/testMachine/Desktop/Event%20Control.application: the
>   manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.        +
>   Manifest XML signature is not valid.      + SignatureDescription could
>   not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY   No transaction error was
>   detected.
>
> WARNINGS  There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS     * [11/10/2013 21:40:23] : Activation of
>   C:\Users\testMachine\Desktop\Event Control.application has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>     * [11/10/2013 21:40:23]
>   System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException
>   (ManifestParse)
>         - Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Users/testMachine/Desktop/Event%20Control.application: the
>   manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String
>   localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore
>   subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState&
>   subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options,
>   ServerInformation& serverInformation)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore
>   subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState&
>   subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)        --- Inner Exception ---
>         System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException
>   (SignatureValidation)
>         - Manifest XML signature is not valid.
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream
>   s)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String
>   localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)      --- Inner
>   Exception ---         System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
>         - SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
>         - Source: System.Security
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm
>   key)          at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm&
>   signingKey)           at
>   System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags
>   verifyFlags)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream
>   s)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS   No transaction information is
>   available.

Comment: You should run the executable from the bin/debug folder instead to install it to your machine(s).  Do you have to make a `ClickOnce` deployment?

Comment: installshield doesnt seem to work for me, so yeah

Comment: When you compile the code though, an executable is created in your `bin\debug` folder that you can copy and take to any machine.  Then you just need to run it.  Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using?  If you are using the full version, they have an installation wizard that you can use to build and MSI.

Comment: you mean using the publish function? ive tried and this is the error it puts out (the log i pasted)

Comment: right, i changed the digital signing key from 256 to 1, it worked, but now its throwing sql  ce execptions everywhere!

Comment: No, I meant using the 'Build' function.  They navigating to the folder where you project is saved to on your hard drive.  In there, is the folder and file I keep referring to.

Comment: Did you sign your ClickOnce app?  Did you full trust your ClickOnce app?  These can be set in the project settings.

Comment: Brian -- they retired the Setup & Deployment projects. They are no longer available after VS2010.

Answer (score 4):

First, in the Signing tab for the project properties, be sure to sign your deployment, even if you just use a test certificate created by Visual Studio. Second, in the Security tab for the project properties, be sure you have ClickOnce security settings enabled. Also, are you editing any of the files after publishing them?

Also be sure your installation URL points to the same location as the deployment, whether it's local disk or a file share or a webserver.

Comment: This URL has more info on the subject: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f5b934d2-e8b9-4401-b038-b84aefbdf836/clickonce-exception-reading-manifest?forum=winformssetup